# How to specify the size of an integer in the migration script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have two columns which require to be declared as `t.integer size(1) and size(2).`
i.e. a max size of 1 (i.e upto 9) and max size of 2 (i.e upto 99). How should I declare this in my migration script.

Comment: I tend to agree with Chris Lewis below.  Is the requirement specifying the range of values allowed for the fields [0..9], and [0..99], which can be left to the model to enforce, or is it truly trying to enforce storage bytes? <- crazy talk for an integer column IMO.

Comment: I agree -- I am not sure what use-case would require the actual storage of an integer to have a size.  If the requirement is to maintain consistency in your data, generally best to let Rails do the work.  Or you could do a stored procedure or check constraint in your database (which I would only recommend if some other process is writing to your database, which I would *not* recommend).

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You should be able to set a :limit on your migration record. Check the documentation here -- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

Ex:
  add_column :my_tbl, :myint, :integer, :limit => 9

This will set a column length -- in other words, it will only allow integers up to 9 digits long.

If you want to restrict the data input for this column, you'll need to do validations in your model. Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#length

Comment: This isn't right. For integer columns, `:limit => 9` means 9 _bytes_ long, not 9 digits.

Answer (score 18):

Do you mean that the value in that column should be restricted to the range 1-99?

Having created an integer column you could add ActiveRecord validation to the model:

```
validates_numericality_of :field_name, :in => 1..99
```